# SQLite database not created while starting my app

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a database for my Android application but it seems it's not created. This is my code:

```
public class PersonDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "data.sqlite";
private static final int VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_PERSON = "person";

private static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NAME = "name";

public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table person ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement "
            + "name varchar(100))");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I call my helper like this:

```
new PersonDatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

When I check is my database present like this:

```
private boolean databaseExists(){
    File database=getActivity().getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("data.sqlite");

    if (!database.exists()) {
        Log.i("Database", "Not Found");
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.i("Database", "Found");
        return true;
    }

}
```

I always receive that database is not found. What am I doing wrong here? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database will be created the first time it is accessed, e.g. by calling `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` on your `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance.